# Pattern Matching for Repeated Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract groups from a string of the format `{{field: value} {field2: value} ... {fieldn: valuen}}`

I'm stuck at `{(.*): (.*)}` - in RegexTester, it matches the entire string (understandable), but in execution, it throws an exception - "Illegal repetition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `{` and `}` should be escaped because they means times to repeat

Second, I think you want to match only parts of your string. You may allow only allowed characters (e.g [a-z0-9]) so that entry string will not be matched

```
\\{([a-z0-9]*): ([a-z0-9]*)\\}
```

As pointed in comments you may allow all characters except some special `[^{}:]`. If I remember correctly you need not escape `{}` in character class.

Comment: thank you. What do you mean by: "You may allow only allowed characters (e.g a-z) so that entry string will not be matched?" Why doesn't .* work?

Comment: Your regexp will match any string that contain `{`, then anything, then ": ", then anything, than } and for your example it will match just all string. Mine will match every field separately [example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%7B(%5Ba-z0-9%5D*)%3A%20(%5Ba-z0-9%5D*)%5C%7D&input=%7B%7Bfield%3A%20value%7D%20%7Bfield2%3A%20value%7D%20...%20%7Bfieldn%3A%20valuen%7D%7D)

Comment: Or just make sure not wanted strings are not matched and still proper escape for special regexp chars like "\\{([^\\{\\}:]*): ([^\\{\\}:]*)\\}". this part [^\{\}:] matches only chars that are not {,} or :.

Answer (score 0):

Escape some chars:

```
"\\{(.*): (.*)\\}"
```

characters } and { have a special meaning and need to be escaped.